# VBA : Insert new column to the left of all columns up until the last column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a column next to each column starting from D, my issue is that the number of columns will change so I need to identify the last column within the code.

Whenever I run the below it doesn't seem to be identifying the last column correctly.

```
Sub InsertColumnsv2()
  Dim iLastCol As Long
  Dim StartCell As Range

  Set StartCell = Range("A1")

  iLastCol = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

  For colx = 4 To iLastCol Step 2
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    iLastCol = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  Next colx
End Sub
```

Comment: You should qualify all your `Columns` with the worksheet you want this code to work on, don't rely on `ActiveSheet` (read my answer below to understand why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it backwards instead

```
Sub InsertColumnsv2()
    Dim iLastCol As Long
    Dim colx As Long

    iLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For colx = iLastCol To 4 Step -1
        Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next colx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Sine you are adding columns in between, the `iLastCol` changes, so you need to loop backwards, use `Step -1` since you are adding a column each step.

**Note**: don't rely on `ActiveSheet`, instead fully qualify your `Columns` and `Cells` object using `With Worksheets("YourSheetName")`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertColumnsv2()

Dim iLastCol As Long, colx As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- change to your sheet's name
    iLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get the last column for the first row

    For colx = iLastCol To 4 Step -1
        .Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next colx
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to solve your insert problem is start from the finish to the start.

```
Sub InsertColumnsv2()
  Dim iLastCol As Long
  Dim StartCell As Range

  Set StartCell = Range("A1")

  iLastCol = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

  For colx = iLastCol  To 4 Step -1
      Columns(colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  Next colx
End Sub
```

Comment: since you are not using the `With Worksheets(...` statement, remove your `.` from `.Columns(colx)` >> this will raise a run-time error